# <name> error while trying to do two or more loops

Tags: lua

Last time I wanted to update my LUA code to be more automatic. Earlier had to turn on and off everything manual, by deleting phrases. But I met small problem **name expected near '2' error** and I'm not sure what's wrong is with it. I was looking in other thread about similar error, but they didn't help me.

```
local BOSS = GetModConfigData("BOSS") --return true or false
local KOAL = GetModConfigData("KOAL") --return true or false
local SCULP = GetModConfigData("SCULP") --return true or false

local BossList = {"BOSS", "KOAL", "SCULP"}
local BossCode = {"bosscode", "koal_old", "koal_new", "sculp_small", "sculp_med", "sculp_big"}
k = 1

for i,v in ipairs(BossList) do
    if BossList[i] == true then

        if BossList[i] == "KOAL" then
            for i,2 do
                Bosses[k] = BossCode[k]
                k = k+1
            end
        elseif BossList[i] == "SCULP" then
            for i,3 do
                Bosses[k] = BossCode[k]
                k = k+1
            end
        else
            Bosses[k] = BossCode[k]
            k = k+1
        end

    end
end
```

When I'm trying to use second loop, problem comes to me. When I pushed this code without second and third loop, it was working. But without save additional BossCodes.

```
for i,v in ipairs(BossList) do
    if BossList[i] == true then
            Bosses[k] = BossCode[k]
            k = k+1
    end
end
```

Comment: `for i,2 do` is not valid Lua code

Comment: I concur with @lhf, as the syntax you are using is not a valid for-loop. Also, it appears that nowhere have you defined the variable `Bosses`; therefore, I can see a problem when you attempt to index `Bosses` with `k`.

Comment: Thanks for help! I fixed this loop asap. Also I forgot to copy ```Bosses``` table because was placed higher than this code.